# Catching requests made in xampp with fiddler

Tags: php, soap, xampp, fiddler

I have a simple php file which makes SOAP requests. This is running on my local computer with XAMPP as a webserver.

I am trying to catch the request made in fiddler, I can see the request to my php file but that just returns the html for the page. I want to catch the request made when I create the SOAP client to see what is being sent off.

Is there some setting in fiddler I need to change to be able to see the response? Or some sort of proxy I can send my request through so it is visible in fiddler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the proxy settings to the SoapClient class like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("request.wsdl", array('proxy_host'     => "localhost",
                                               'proxy_port'     => 8888));
```

This assumes that fiddler is running on it's default port (8888).